# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x}$

Tags: calculus

how can one evaluate the limit below?

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x}$$

Using L'Hôpital's rule seems to provide no progress: as x approaches zero from the left, $\frac{1}{x}$ approaches $-\infty$, so we have an indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$. Deriving both equations,

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}} \cdot \left[\frac{1}{x} \right]'}{1} = - \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2}$$

$$$$

Thank you.

Comment: Let $x=-1/t$, and things become familiar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $-\dfrac1x=y$ to get $$\lim_{y\to+\infty}\dfrac y{e^y}=\lim_{y\to+\infty}\dfrac1{e^y}=\cdots$$